# <del> without <ins>?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design

Markdown accepts the `<del>` tag, which is very convenient if you want to remove a word, sentence, or paragraph but want to do this in a non-confusing manner. But many times you want to *replace* a word (say) with a new, more appropriate, word. And if you want to do this in a non-confusing manner, you need the `<ins>` tag as well. But Markdown doesn't allow this tag. Please change!

Comment: It would be nice, but what do you think `<ins>` should look like? Green color? Imagine the spam of colors, it doesn't suit SO. If you want to add some emphasis on what's new I guess you could use `bold` and/or `italic`.

Comment: Related but unanswered: [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user/33641#33641)

Comment: @BrunoLM: a slight grayish (#222) bold?

Comment: @perbert: Testing here... `#888 bold` seems ok. It would be a grayed bold. I'm not sure if I liked it at all :P. But I guess I wouldn't mind seen that around. `#222 bold` and `bold` looks like the same :P