# Inbox bug: Processing html tags (XSS possible?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

I received a comment reply [on this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65627/del-without-ins). Since it was <del>like this</del>, I though the comment was deleted or something like that, but then I noticed the topic title has HTML tags. These tags are being processed on the inbox resulting in:

> comment on <del>without ?</del>
>
> <del>@BrunoLM: a slight grayish (#222) bold?</del>

But it should be

```
comment on <del> without <ins>?

@BrunoLM: a slight grayish (#222) bold?
```

Comment: This could make XSS possible.

Comment: **To close voters**: the issue was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is intended for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, not for actual bugs that are later marked completed. The [tag:status-completed] tag is enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

oops! thanks for catching that. definitely serious; fixed.